# Trying to install cURL in php5 under apache2.4 (windows 7)

Tags: php, apache, curl

Im trying to install curl and im using windows 7. i installed Apache 2.4.9 from www.apachelounge.com/download/ and Php 5.3 vc9 from windows.php.net/download/. Php is working fine.

Now i got curl 7.34.0 from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
followed all the instructions from http://www.tonyspencer.com/2003/10/22/curl-with-php-and-apache-on-windows/ The topic is very old and uses php4 but i still got everything done. also followed www.strikeawe.com/blog/2009/03/installing-apache-php-and-curl-on-windows (2009 topic)... checked phpinfo() and found that curl isn't installed. this is the first time ever im posting. usually www.google.com/ was enough. please help :'(

Comment: _checked phpinfo() and found that php isn't installed._ Umm how do you run phpinfo if php is not installed?

Comment: Don't you mean cURL is not installed?

Comment: I installed wampserver. Then I only needed to remove the `;` at the start of the curl line in the php.ini file

Comment: You dont need to install CURL, you just need to activate the extension by uncommenting this line in php.ini `extension=php_curl.dll`

Comment: Yea, looks like that _Tony Spencer_ tutorial is full of bad advice. Ignore it or rather work backwards and **UNDO Everything suggested**

Comment: Why you installed Apache and PHP separately? There are many solutions, all in one, like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [XAMMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/ro/index.html). Don't try to reinvent the wheel, it's not gonna get rounder ;)

Comment: ughh i meant curl is not installed. im so mixed up right now

Comment: my suggestion is to ignore windows, and install vmware and get a linux/gnu vm up and running

Comment: And @RiggsFolly uncommenting extension=php_curl.dll only enables the curl extension you have to get curl installed.

Comment: Slash - Good, you dont need to install curl unless yo want to use it from the command line. PHP does not need it 'installed'

Comment: Sorry Slash, but you are so wrong on that. I use Apache/PHP and code cURL in PHP and I have NEVER installed CURL

Comment: @RPM There is always one... well normally more than one, but whatever.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I don't follow

Comment: In any case uncommenting extension=php_curl.dll is not doing it. while the rest of the php is working fine

Comment: You need to have the php_curl.dll installed. it will be located in `php/ext`

Comment: i checked.. it is there @RPM

Comment: restart apache after making changes to `php.ini`

Comment: php_curl.dll need access to libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll maybe if you just copy those to your apache/bin directory you will get better results.  PS, they dont need to be in the windows\system32 folder

Comment: Done that too mr riggs

Comment: Well I guess you are not up to Installing and configuring APache/PHP/MySQL manually. Thats NOT A DIG, lots of people have problems doing this themselves manually. Take a look at WAMPServer or XAMPP. It all gets done at the click of an install with those. BUT UNINSTALL all the stuff you have currently done or it will become a real mess.

Comment: Thank you all for your time